# How does python read lines from file

Tags: python

Consider the following simple python code:

```
f=open('raw1', 'r')
i=1
for line in f:
    line1=line.split()
    for word in line1:
        print word,
print '\n'
```

In the first for loop i.e "for line in f:", how does python know that I want to read a line and not a word or a character?

The second loop is clearer as line1 is a list. So the second loop will iterate over the list elemnts.

Comment: Because that's been given in the definition? Docs -> `For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code`

Comment: As Surkrit says, it's simply a matter of the defined behaviour - iterators can give whatever they want on each iteration, and that's how files have been written to function. It's worth noting that when working with files in Python, it is best to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) as it can stop obscure bugs, and is more readable.

Comment: thanks Sukrit and Lattyware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a notation of what are called "iterables". They're things that know how to let you traverse some data they hold. Some common iterators are lists, sets, dicts, pretty much every data structure. Files are no exception to this.

The way things become iterable is by defining a method to return an object with a `next` method. This `next` method is meant to be called repeatedly and return the next piece of data each time. The `for foo in bar` loops actually are just calling the `next` method repeatedly behind the scenes.

For files, the `next` method returns lines, that's it. It doesn't "know" that you want lines, it's just always going to return lines. The reason for this is that ~50% of cases involving file traversal are by line, and if you want words,

```
 for word in (word for line in f for word in line.split(' ')):
     ...
```

works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Also, how can i learn to simplify my code, like the one you've mentioned in your answer. If you could tell me a link where i can learn this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm using a (somewhat convoluted) generator expression. If you want to learn about them the docs are good http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

Answer (score 3):

In python the **for..in** syntax is used over iterables (elements tht can be iterated upon). For a file object, the iterator is the file itself.

Please refer [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-file-objects.html) to the documentation of **next()** method - excerpt pasted below:

> A file object is its own iterator, for example iter(f) returns f
>   (unless f is closed). When a file is used as an iterator, typically in
>   a for loop (for example, for line in f: print line), the next() method
>   is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or
>   raises StopIteration when EOF is hit when the file is open for reading
>   (behavior is undefined when the file is open for writing). In order to
>   make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a
>   file (a very common operation), the next() method uses a hidden
>   read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer,
>   combining next() with other file methods (like readline()) does not
>   work right. However, using seek() to reposition the file to an
>   absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer. New in version
>   2.3.